# Remove remote .git Heroku files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, github

I deleted my Heroku app from the management console, but when I tried to create a new app using the same repository it is still trying to push to the old app, I ran the following command to see the git files

```
git remote -v
```

which returned these files

```
origin  git@github.com:Jbur43/all-bugs-aside.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:Jbur43/all-bugs-aside.git (push)
```

I them tried running `git rm all-bugs-aside.git` and `git rm git@github.com:Jbur43/all-bugs-aside.git` and `git rm all-bugs aside`

I also tried running all of those commands with -rf, but I could not get the files to delete.

Can someone help me with the syntax needed to remove these files and also once they are removed I should be able to create a new heroku app and push to `git push heroku master`, correct?

Comment: Try removing, **.git** from your project.

Comment: Where is that? I only see .gitignore @Sahil

Comment: Enter **ls -xa** in console, you will see one hidden folder **.git**, plus what does it show when you enter, **git remote**.

Comment: **git remote** shows **origin**

Comment: You have not added heroku as remote in your project till now. To add first create app on heroku by typing: **heroku create** inside your code folder, and then **git push heroku master**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the remote that points to heroku ("origin" is the remote's name): `git remote rm origin`

Other .git files aren't Heroku's files but your project's source control.